# Two Spinner and Array

Tags: arrays, spinner

I'm studing android and the excercise I'll do is this one:
You have the Five Continental with relative state/capital. 
Create an Activity with two spinner and une button .
When you select Continent from the first spinner the second spinner should display only the state of the relative continent. When you click on the button a dialog box should show:
Continental: Selected Contiental;
State:Selected State;
StateCapital: the capital of the state.
I don't want to use any db (I'm a dummy at the moment) can you help me ?
I think is more simple to use arrays.

I Create my string xml

```
<string name="Select_continent">Select Continent</string>
<string-array name="continent">
<item>Usa</item>
<item>Europe</item>
<item>Australia</item>
<item>Asia</item>
<item>Africa</item>
</string-array>

<string name="Select_state_usa">Select State</string>
<string-array name="Usa">
<item>Alabama</item>
<item>Ohio</item>
<item>Florida</item>
<item>...</item>

<string name="Select_state_eu">Select State</string>
<string-array name="Europe">
<item>Germany</item>
<item>Italy</item>
<item>England</item>
<item>...</item>
```

Then I create my main.xml

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:entries="@array/continent"
android:prompt="@string/Select_continent"
android:gravity="center"
 />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Select continent:"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="297dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
   />
```

And then I create MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity  {

private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private Button btnSubmit;
final Context context = this;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.Myactivity);
addItemsOnSpinner2();
addListenerOnButton();
addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
}

//add items into spinner dynamically
public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Austria");
list.add("Italy"); 
list.add("Germany"); 
list.add("France");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
}

 //get the selected dropdown list value
public void addListenerOnButton() {

spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder3 = new  AlertDialog.Builder
(context);
alertDialogBuilder3
.setTitle("Continent")
.setIcon(R.drawable.info)
.setMessage("Continent " + "\n " + String.valueOf (spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
 "\n " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()) +
"\nCapital : "  )
.setNeutralButton("Ok",null)
.create() // create one
.show();
}
});

}}
```

Can you help me to add the relative state to the continent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize both spinners, populate the continent spinner and set `OnItemSelected()` listener, switch-case on the selected item, populate the second spinner according to the case.

**EDITED:**

Sure! Please note, however that I am currently on my tablet so I will not be able to test out the code before handing it out to you.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity 
{

    ArrayList<String> continents; 
    ArrayList<String> statesOfContA; 
    ArrayList<String> statesOfContB;

    Spinner conts;
    Spinner states;

    Button btnShowToast;

    String continentValue;
    String stateValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        btnShowToast = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

        continents = new ArrayList<String>();
        statesOfContA = new ArrayList<String>();
        statesOfContB = new ArrayList<String>();

        continents.add("Continent A");
        continents.add("Continent B");

        statesOfContA.add("State A");
        statesOfContA.add("State B");

        statesOfContB.add("State A");
        statesOfContB.add("State B");

        conts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spConts);
        states = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spStates);

        ArrayAdapter<String> contAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, continents);
        conts.setAdapter(contAdapter);

        conts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                long arg3)
            {
                ArrayAdapter<String> stateAdapter;
                String choice = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                continentValue = continents.getSelectedItem().toString();

                switch(choice)
                {
                    case "Continent A":
                        stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, statesOfContA);
                        states.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
                        break;
                    case "Continent B":
                        stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, statesOfContB);
                        states.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
                        break;
               }
               Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Continent: " + continentValue + " State: " + stateValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
               t.show();
           }

        });

    btnShowToast.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Continent: " continentValue + " State: " + stateValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            t.show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Watch out for any spelling mistakes as well!  If this doesn't work, kindly let me know so we can find another solution :)

Good luck!

Comment: Dear Claire, can you give me an example please?

Comment: Edited the answer.  I am very sorry for the late reply, and I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Here I hava an error:                  continentValue =  ((AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter>) continents).getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: continentValue = continents.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: conts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()

Comment: and here:    continentValue = continents.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Nothing...the code is red-underlined. However I have this warning: Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Comment: I do not have the code because I am posting here from my tablet.

Comment: 1.  right-click on your project and select "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties" (if this doesn't work, try second option)
2.  right-click on your project and select "Properties -> Java Compiler", check "Enable project specific settings" and select 1.5 or 1.6 from "Compiler compliance settings" select box.

Comment: Done but I still have the red-underline on "conts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() " : The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type Spinner is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

Comment: I'm very sorry, it was my mistake. Replace that exact same line with this: `conts.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()`

Comment: That error was being shown because Spinners cannot have OnItemClickListeners but rather OnItemSelectedListeners.  I truly apologize.

Comment: OK! this is ok, there are some other errors, can I post them? continentValue = continents.getSelectedItem().toString();----conts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spConts); ---  switch(choice)

Comment: Are you replacing the variable names with those in your code? **Example:** `R.id.spConts` should be replaced with `R.id.[YOUR_SPINNER_ID]`

Comment: Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

Comment: so use an if-else if statement instead.... I'm surprised you couldn't come up with that.